# How can I forcefully cache all my HTTP responses?

Tags: java, android

I'm using the `DefaultHTTPClient` to make some HTTP GET requests. I'd like to forcefully cache all the HTTP responses for a week. After going through the docs and some SO answers, I've done this:

I installed an `HttpResponseCache` via the `onCreate` method of my main activity.

```
    try {
        File httpCacheDir = new File(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), "http");
        long httpCacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
        HttpResponseCache.install(httpCacheDir, httpCacheSize);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("dd", "HTTP response cache installation failed:" + e);
    }
```

I added a custom `HttpResponseInterceptor` for my HTTP client, but I still don't get a cache hit. Here's my response interceptor that decompresses GZIPped content, strips caching headers and adds a custom one:

```
class Decompressor implements HttpResponseInterceptor {

    public void process(HttpResponse hreResponse, HttpContext hctContext) throws HttpException, IOException {

        hreResponse.removeHeaders("Expires");
        hreResponse.removeHeaders("Pragma");
        hreResponse.removeHeaders("Cache-Control");
        hreResponse.addHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=604800");

        HttpEntity entity = hreResponse.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            Header ceheader = entity.getContentEncoding();
            if (ceheader != null) {
                HeaderElement[] codecs = ceheader.getElements();
                for (int i = 0; i < codecs.length; i++) {
                    if (codecs[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                        hreResponse.setEntity(new HttpEntityWrapper(entity) {
                            @Override
                            public InputStream getContent() throws IOException, IllegalStateException {
                                return new GZIPInputStream(wrappedEntity.getContent());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public long getContentLength() {
                                return -1;
                            }
                        });
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here's how I make my request:

```
String strResponse = null;

HttpGet htpGet = new HttpGet(strUrl);
htpGet.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
htpGet.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1");
DefaultHttpClient dhcClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
dhcClient.addResponseInterceptor(new Decompressor(), 0);
HttpResponse resResponse = dhcClient.execute(htpGet);
Log.d("helpers.network", String.format("Cache hit count: %d", HttpResponseCache.getInstalled().getHitCount()));

strResponse = EntityUtils.toString(resResponse.getEntity());

return strResponse;
```

I can't seem to pinpoint what I'm doing wrong. Would any of you know?

Comment: Idk what `HttpResonseCache` does but you could create a file cache  encapsulating HttpClient manually or you could try using `HttpUrlConnection` which has a cache since ICS http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

Comment: There is a Header Information called cache-control, I am not sure it could help or not but do some research on that, if you still wonder what to do.

Comment: @Dhruvenkumar Shah, If you look at my code, you'll see that I'm manually setting the `Cache-Control` header.

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla Sorry about that my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed miserably with this. According to the Android documentation, it specifically says about the `HttpResponseCache` — *"Caches HTTP and HTTPS responses to the filesystem so they may be reused, saving time and bandwidth. This class supports HttpURLConnection and HttpsURLConnection; there is no platform-provided cache for DefaultHttpClient or AndroidHttpClient."*

So that was out.

Now Apache's HTTP client has a `CachingHttpClient` and this new version of HTTP client has been back ported to Android through [this project](http://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/). Of course, I could use this.

I didn't want to use the hackish version of the Apache HTTP Client libraries so one idea was to cannibalise the caching related bits from the HTTP Client and reoll my own but it was too much work.

I even considered moving to the recommended `HttpURLConnection` class as recommended but I've run into other issues. There doesn't seem to be good cookie-persistence implementation for that class.

Anyway, I skipped everything and though. I'm reducing the loading time by caching, why not got go a step further and since I was using jSoup to scrape records from the page and create an `ArrayList` of a custom structure, I might as well serialize the whole `ArrayList` by implementing the `Serializable` method on my structure. Now I don't have to wait for the page request, not do I have to wait for the jSoup parsing slowness. Win.

Comment: Not sure if this is also of help, but there is a bunch of information here about implementing caching, not specific to Android but hopefully helpful. https://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=9700192

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question, but instead of relying on an HTTP server interpreting your cache control headers, have you thought about simply adding a client-side cache using Android's own cache directories?

What we did in ignition is simply write server responses to disk as byte streams, thus having full control over caching (and expiring caches.)

There's a sample app [here](https://github.com/kaeppler/ignition), but it would require you to use the library's HTTP API (which, however, is merely a thin wrapper around HttpClient.) Or simply look at how the cache works and go from there.

Comment: if you look at my code, you'll see that I'm not relying on the server on interpreting my headers. I'm dealing with the response object. I'm stripping out all the headers and and adding a custom `Cache-Control` header.

Comment: Okay I see. That seems like a wild hack to me. Moreover, you continue to consume the response in the same response interceptor, so why would this be cached anywhere?

Comment: you have a point. I cant remove my `HttpResponseInterceptor` else I wouldn't be able to decompress GZIPped content. Do you have any other ideas? I'd like to stick with the `HTTPClient` and not switch over to `HTTPURLConnection`. Thanks.

Comment: To be honest, I haven't used the built-in cache functionality of HttpClient, but I'd be surprised if there wasn't the possibility for both having a gzip interceptor and make use of the caching at the same time. Quickly glancing over http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/caching.html suggests you should use `CachingHttpClient`, not `DefaultHttpClient`. Have you looked into that?